# dropout regularization in gbm

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, boosting, dropout

**Background:**
Dropout regularization reduces overfitting in Neural networks, especially deep belief networks ([srivastava14a](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume15/srivastava14a/srivastava14a.pdf)).  It also has the opportunity to accelerate learning because individual learning iterations are on a reduced set of the model.

The gradient boosted tree (like those xgboost or gbm) is known for being an excellent ensemble learner, but one that suffers from over-fitting.

**Question:**
Is there an analog to dropout regression that is used in GBM learning?
Does "subsampling" or "stochastic gradient learning" relate to this - does it count as a version of dropout regression?

I think that the stochastic gradient learning is about "randomly disabling inputs" and not "randomly disabling individual learners".

Comment: For me neural net dropout is analogue to random variable subspace aka. mtry of random forests. In the RF model each node can only be split by a random fraction of features, hereby achieving more a regularized ensemble. I see that the [xgboost package][1] has a `colsample_bytree` option which can reduce the number of variables available for each tree. This could be seen as an analouge to dropout.


  [1]: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xgboost/xgboost.pdf

Comment: Does gradient boosting suffer from overfitting?  With proper use of early stopping and learning rates, I have always been able to use it effectively.

Comment: @MatthewDrury It can still overfit (easier than Random Forests for example) though.

Comment: @Firebug Huh.  I wonder what I was thinking when I posted that...

Comment: @MatthewDrury Haha happens to us all xD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out this paper: [DART: Dropouts meet Multiple Additive Regression Trees (Arxiv PDF)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.01866.pdf).

Their interpertation of dropout is this: instead of developing the next tree from the residual of *all* previous trees, develop the next tree from the residual of a *sample* of previous trees. The effect on the model is similar in that individual components are forced to be more self-sufficient. They observe some reasonably significant gains.

As Soren points out, `colsample_bytree` and `colsample_bylevel` are analogous to input-layer dropout.

DART is available in xgboost already by setting `booster="dart"`

Comment: my version says "gblinear" or "gbtree" and does not give "dart".  Is there another library that I need for xgboost in r to do this?

Comment: It got added very recently, so your version may be slightly out of date or they may not have pushed it to the stable channels. You can get the most up-to-date version by installing from their github repository. https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost. For R: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/tree/master/R-package